# restrict documents for mapreduce with mongoid

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce, mongoid

I implemented the pearson product correlation via map / reduce / finalize. The missing part is to restrict the documents (representing users) to be processed via a filter query. For a simple query like

```
mapreduce(mapper, reducer, :finalize => finalizer, :query => { :name => 'Bernd' })
```

I get this to work.

But my filter criteria is a little bit more complicated: I have one set of preferences which need to have at least one common element and another set of preferences which may not have a common element. In a later step I also want to restrict this to documents (users) within a certain geographical distance.

Currently I have this code working in my map function, but I would prefer to separate this into either query params as supported by mongoid or a javascript function. All my attempts to solve this failed since the code is either ignored or raises an error.

I did a couple of tests.

[results deleted, see below]

I'm using ruby 1.9.2, mongodb 1.6.5-x86_64, and the mongoid 2.0.0.beta.20, mongo 1.1.5 and bson 1.1.5 gems on MacOS.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

More Tests (problem partly solved):

```
User.where(:name.in => ["Arno", "Bernd", "Claudia"])
```

works, however when using mapreduce like this

```
mapreduce(..., :query => { :name.in => ['Arno', 'Bernd', 'Claudia'] })
```

results in the bson error *serialize: keys must be strings or symbols (TypeError)* mentioned above.

Replacing `:name.in` with `'name.in'` or `'name.$in'` makes the query return no results (guess this is passed as is to mongodb).

However

```
mapreduce(..., :query => { :name => { '$in' => ['Arno', 'Bernd', 'Claudia'] } })
```

works, but I didn't have any success with my geospatial query attempts, no matter how I wrote the expression.

```
mapreduce(..., :query => {:location => { "$near" => [ 13, 52, 1 ] } })
```

results in this error_message: *Database command 'mapreduce' failed: {"assertion"=>"manual matcher config not allowed",...*.

If anyone could give me an idea how to write a geospatial query using `near` or `within` and working with mapreduce I would be very happy. (I didn't play with sets yet, see above).

Comment: Just forgot to mention that spatial queries with mapreduce do not work yet (at least in mongodb 1.6.x). Also I'm planning to provide a code sample soon to show how to do the pearson product correlation with map / reduce / finalize.

Comment: Here's the [link](http://sparetimer-dev.blogspot.com/2011/02/pearson-correlation-example-with.html) to a **working example**.

Comment: mapreduce with spatial query support is planned for 1.9 http://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-1742